# {file} didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to use a Nuxt.JS template but I have some assets that don't load in compiled mode but still load in development mode.

I get this kind of line many times at compile time and I suspect it's coming from there:

```
hero-22.jpg referenced in /src/assets/css/main.scss didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
```

I also have a Typescript error on my nuxt configuration file (nuxt.config.js):

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    alias: {
        "@": resolve(__dirname, "/")
    },
    app: {
        head: {
            meta: [{ name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" }],
            title: "Martex - Software, App, SaaS & Startup NuxtJS Template",
            script: []
        }
    },
    ...
```

Here's how most assets are integrated into CSS:

```css
.theme--dark #hero-15 {
    background-image: url(hero-15-dark.jpg);
}
```

All images called from HTML Vue files load, but CSS images do not.